# Laravel Supervisor: How to process certains jobs in sequence?

Tags: laravel, supervisord

I have three jobs in my app:

SendEmail, ProcessOrder, SendNotification

and this it my supervisor config:

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /app/artisan queue:work --queue=email,order,notify --tries=5 --sleep=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/app/worker.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

How can i tell to supervisor process the `ProcessOrder` (order queue) in sequence and no multiple at the same time? If i have 5 jobs in my queue as i set `numprocs` to 8 supervisor try to process all of them at the same time but i want it to process `ProcessOrder` one by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to create a additional supervisor process which has `numprocs=1` wherein you process only your order queue. Similarly update your existing process to work on the other two queues.

This way you wont have multiple sub process to handle your order queue. Hence will process tasks one after the other, whereas all your other queues will have multiple process to handle them.